# How can I make NetBeans's Javascript formatter JSLint compliant?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, formatting, jslint

[Douglas Crockford's Code Conventions for JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) state that

> There should be no space between the name of a function and the ( (left parenthesis) of its parameter list.

and

> If a function literal is anonymous, there should be one space between the word function and the ( (left parenthesis). If the space is omited, then it can appear that the function's name is function, which is an incorrect reading.

So far I have only been able to get NetBeans's formatter to do either

```
function test() {}
function() {}
```

or

```
function test () {}
function () {}
```

What I would like to get is this

```
function test() {}
function () {}
```

Is there a way to get NetBeans's to follow this convention or failing that is there a plugin that can accomplish this?

Comment: Are we talking about http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43263/jsbeautify ?

Comment: @PaulS. I had looked at this (although I hadn't noticed the "JSLint Happy" option). However, it doesn't have enough options for customising how it works and is changing things that JSLint doesn't require.